# How to check if column containing array is equal to another array provided by us in Spark DataFrame?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a DF what a column that contains array.
The structure looks like this for each rows:

```
+---------------+------------+-----------+---------+-----------+-------------+
|table_name     |table_schema|column_name|data_type|column_size|column_tokens|
+---------------+------------+-----------+---------+-----------+-------------+
|sales          |demo        |sales_id   |int      |100        |[sales, id]  |
+---------------+------------+-----------+---------+-----------+-------------+
```

> Now I want to query if any row's column_tokens contains exactly
> [sales, id] , return me that.

I used query like this to get the above DF ,

```
selectedTableInfo.filter(array_contains(col("column_tokens"),"id")).show(100,false)
```

Is there any way to do Array to Array match ?

Like :

```
 selectedTableInfo.filter(array_equals(col("column_tokens"),Seq("sales","id"))).show(100,false)
```

Comment: Why not to use `col("column_tokens") === array(lit("sales"), lit("id"))`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the equality condition with `array` function. Here is a sample.

```
val df = spark.createDataFrame(Seq(("1", Seq("a", "b")))).toDF("id", "array")
df.show

+---+------+
| id| array|
+---+------+
|  1|[a, b]|
+---+------+

df.filter(col("array") === array(lit("a"), lit("b"))).show

+---+------+
| id| array|
+---+------+
|  1|[a, b]|
+---+------+
```

Comment: Hi, it works , but it needs ordering to be similar as expected. But can we just check if the contents are similar ? 

Seq("a","b") == Seq("b","a")

Answer (score 0):

You could also use **isin()**.

```
val df = spark.createDataFrame(
    Seq(
        ("1", Seq("a", "b")), 
        ("2", Seq("c", "d"))
    )
).toDF(
    "id", 
    "sales"
)
df.show()

df.filter(
    col("sales").isin(array(lit("a"), lit("b")))
).show()
```